# How to output elements in an array with four or more letters in PHP and state how many times they occur

Tags: php, arrays

How do I output the words with four or more letters in them from the array and state how many times they occur?

```
$selection = array("house", "are", "better", "love", "dog",
    "love", "don't", "me", "like", "apples", "frank", "better", "you", 
    "like", "house", "better", "love", "cream");
$array2 = array();
foreach ($selection as $word) {
    if (strlen($word) >= 4) {
        $array2[] = $word;
        print_r(array_count_values($word));
    }
}
return $array2;
foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
    printf("The word '$key' appears $value times<br>\n");
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is with your code? Is there an error message? Does it count up wrongly?

Comment: it doesnt output anything

Comment: I'll suggest adding some debugging - add an `echo` call inside the first loop, so you can get it to print out the value of `$word` each time; then the same inside your `if` statement, to see if the code is reaching there. You've also got a `return` statement before the second loop - do you want it there?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code. You should use the word as the array key, and maintain a running count.

Also, you are calling `return`, which effectively stops the script.

Finally, use more descriptive variable names to help keep track of what you're doing.

```
<?php
$selection = array("house", "are", "better", "love", "dog",
                   "love", "don't", "me", "like", "apples", "frank", "better", "you", 
                   "like", "house", "better", "love", "cream");
$results = array();
foreach ($selection as $word) {
    if (strlen($word) >= 4) {
        if (array_key_exists($word, $results) == false)
            $results[$word] = 0;
        $results[$word]++;
    }
}
foreach ($results as $word=>$count) {
    print "The word '$word' appears $count times<br>\n";
}
?>
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/pq89ic

**Documentation & Related Reading**

- `return` - https://www.php.net/return
- Arrays - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php
- *7+1 tips for naming variables* on Making Good Software - http://www.makinggoodsoftware.com/2009/05/04/71-tips-for-naming-variables/

Answer (score 0):

Do This:

```
<?
$selection = array("house", "are", "better", "love", "dog",
    "love", "don't", "me", "like", "apples", "frank", "better", "you", 
    "like", "house", "better", "love", "cream");
$array2 = array();
foreach ($selection as $word) {
    if (strlen($word) >= 4) {
        if (isset($array2[$word])) $array2[$word]++;
            else $array2[$word] = 1;
    }
}
foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
    printf("The word '$key' appears $value times<br>\n");
}
?>
```

**[SEE WORKING CODE](http://codepad.org/Kpk7zCjX)**

Comment: I suspect that this will generate warnings, because the first time you encounter a word that meets the criteria, you're incrementing `$array2[$word]` without setting a value first.

Comment: @andrewsi That generates a notice, but yes, not good practice to ignore.

Comment: @Chris - ah, yes. I couldn't remember if it was a warning or a notice!

Comment: @user1821728 that is more complicated, maybe loop it a second time.